# Excel - Insert rows by shifting cells down - without format loss - Change default shift operation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, copy-paste

I have an excel sheet as shown below. As I don't have privilege to paste image, it is uploaded as link

[image: Original data format]

I would like to insert the highlighted records on top of the rows shown.

When I select all the 4 rows and 2 columns to be copied and click on "Insert cut cells", it doesn't work the way I want it. Instead the output looks like as shown below which is incorrect. As you can see, the 'father', 'mother', 'brother' rows which have to be below the pasted/inserted records, is moved to the next column.This is incorrect and not an expected output

[image: Incorrect image copy pasted]

Hence, I would like to be able to get the output as shown below

Is it possible in Excel to get an output as shown below by copy and paste/insert?

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do with this with the help of a simple macro/vba code. AFAIK, Excel doesn't have any option to change the default when inserting rows

```
Sub ShiftDown()
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```